# The Update Statement is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string resetpassword = rnd.Next(5000, 100000).ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HealthDBContext"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string reset = "UPDATE Users SET" + " Password=@pass" + " WHERE UserName=@user";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(reset, conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", resetpassword);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text);
    conn.Close();
}
```

For some reason, the password is not updated.

Comment: Ooooh, please tell me you aren't storing passwords in plain text in a real application.

Comment: use this method `ExecuteNonQuery();`, only when you are `inserting`, `deleting`, `updating`; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query:

```
int cnt = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The method returns the number of affected rows.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Always forgetting that line :(

Answer (score 1):

Execute query

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string resetpassword = rnd.Next(5000, 100000).ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HealthDBContext"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string reset = "UPDATE Users SET" + " Password=@pass" + " WHERE UserName=@user";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(reset, conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", resetpassword);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```